# Make tab switching conditional

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a basic TAB interface and was wondering if there is a way upon tab click, to check a condition. Depending on the condition we go ahead with the tab change or not.

Looking at the methods available, i could not find anything that would help me.

onChange and onTabClick do not seem to work for what im trying to do, any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if is possible in your version but u can do it like this:
(In the exemple i don't set up any logic but you can do what ever you want in the button)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeKey: "1"
  };

  handleChange = activeKey => {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Current antd version: {version}</p>
        <div>
          <Tabs
            type="primary"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
          >
            <TabPane tab="First" key="1">
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({ activeKey: "2" });
                }}
              >
                Go to Second Tab
              </Button>
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tab="Second" key="2">
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({ activeKey: "1" });
                }}
              >
                Back to first tab
              </Button>
            </TabPane>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit broken-sound-5897p]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element you have focus on, you can use the `onKeyDown` prop. Then, just check the condition to call `preventDefault()`

```
onKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (condition) event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont think this solves the problem. For your reference im talking about this component: https://ant.design/components/tabs/